# Limit clause while using boundary query in sqoop

Tags: sqoop

Why we have to use limit clause with boundary query option in sqoop-import

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use *LIMIT* clause in boundary query.

Example:

```
--boundary-query 'SELECT 0, MAX(id) FROM table'
```

If you don't specify then by default sqoop will use:

```
select min(<split-by>), max(<split-by>) from <table name>
```